# Clearing Tomcat's DNS cache

Tags: domain-name-system, tomcat

To my understanding Tomcat uses separate DNS-cache on Linux. How can I clear it ?

Our Tomcat server is running an app that uses service on another server that got it's IP-address changed. Now I am getting *noRouteToHost* exceptions even when the service on the another server seems to be accessible using it's DNS name when testing from another computer. Also when pinging the the "new-IP" server from the server that got tomcat installed using its DNS name the ping pings the correct new IP address.

Comment: Additional question: Does tomcat or java have some place where you could define static ip dns-name pairs. Similar to lmhosts in windows.

Comment: Rebooting tomcat solved the problem.

Comment: Well, as you're running Tomcat on Linux, you could use OS /etc/hosts file for static hostname / IP addr mappings (which is equivalent to lmhosts file in Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle/Sun Java offers internal cache for it's own name resolution mechanism (it is not specific to Apache Tomcat servlet container).

For now, it seems that easiest solution would be restart whole JVM container. Later, if you want to completely disable internal DNS cache, you can do this by setting `networkaddress.cache.ttl` and `networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl` system properties to 0 (more about these Java properties [can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)).

Comment: networkaddress.cache.ttl and networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl is not system.properties. You need update java.security